# How to convert a Crystal Report file (RPT) from Access to Microsoft Sql Server?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I have taken over support of an application that was originally written in VB.Net net and has now been ported to C#. The application originally made use of an Access database which I have now migrated to Microsoft SQL Server 2008. Everything is working fine except for the reports which were built with Crystal Reports. I have never worked with Crystal Reports before and I am struggling to get the .RPT files converted to work with Sql Server instead of Access.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and have installed Crystal Reports 13.0.1 for VS. Now when I open one of the RPT files I see "Field Explorer" with "Database fields" tree item which I can expand to show a single table. If I right click on "Database fields" and select "Verify Database" a window popups up with the title "Access/Excel (DAO)" and fields "Database Name" showing the path to a .mdb file and "Database Type" with "Access" shown here. If I dropdown "Database Type" I see only file based databases listed here, such as "dBase 5.0", "Excel 8.0", "Paradox 5.x", etc.

So how do I change "Database Fields" to read my Sql Server database rather than Access?

UPDATE:

Ok. I am most of the way there now. I have managed to connect to the database with Database Expert (Right clicking on "Database Fields" and then selecting "Database Expert" from the context menu). I then expanded "Create New Connection" then "OLE DB (ADO)" and was able to select "SQL Server Native Client 10.0" from the provider list. In this way I was able to add a link to the Sql Server database.

Then I tried going to "Set Database Location.." and updating the provider from the .mdb under "My Connections" to the Sql Database which is now listed there and then selecting "Update". This works fine if only tables are linked and these are present in the Sql Database (which they are). But if the report has a command (sql query) then the update fails because the syntax of the command is not correct for Sql Server. I can delete the command and recreate it under the Sql Server connection with the correct syntax, but then I lose all the fields on the report that were linked to the original command. This is not too much of an issue cos I can manually recreate these, but I am wondering if there is a way change the syntax of commands when setting the database location to the Sql Server?

Answer (score 0):

rem the lines of the sql code, then do the db update, then update the sql code.